# Does the JP version of the PS3 Ni No Kuni have English subtitles?

Tags: ni-no-kuni-wrath-of-the-white-witch

Studio Ghibli's *Ni No Kuni: Wrath of the White Witch* is slated for a PS3 US release in late 2012/early 2013, but as I can't wait I'm looking at getting the JP version from Play-Asia or similar.

Does it have English subtitles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Like with most Japanese games, there are no English subtitles, because the game is marketed to the Japanese audience (who speak and read Japanese).

Worry not! The [western localized version will have English subtitles](http://www.nowgamer.com/news/1326011/ni_no_kuni_level5_planning_additional_enhancements_dlc_for_the_west.html) and the (original) Japanese voices, additional content, and DLC content.

I can say for a fact that there are no English subtitles in the game. This is what the gameplay dialogue looks like:

There are some intricacies and nuances the dialogues that would make an accurate English translation tricky.

For the most part you can play through most of the game without needing decipher those (Japanese) moonrunes. Though there are some parts where you might get stuck, but that's what [GameFAQs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/998014-ni-no-kuni-wrath-of-the-white-witch) is for.